# Mapping list of lists in python

Tags: python, list, mapping

I have a list of list something like this:

```
l=[[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]

l1,l2,l3 = [],[],[]
for i in xrange(0,len(l)):
    l1.append(l[i][0])
    l2.append(l[i][1])
    l3.append(l[i][2])
```

So that I will get:

```
l1=[1,1,1]
l2=[2,2,2]
l3=[3,3,3]
```

I am interested in finding a better way of doing this. For example, if I were to add more values (l4, l5 ... etc.) could I find a way that would make it more dynamic rather than having to keep adding lists. Is there a way to map this somehow to give me something like:

```
new_l=[[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[3,3,3]]
```

Note: it is the positions that matter, these values were just used for simplicity.

Answer (score 3):

Using `zip` function:

```
>>> list(zip(*l)) # You don't need list() in Python 2
[(1, 1, 1), (2, 2, 2), (3, 3, 3)]
```

This returns a list of tuples, if you need a list of lists:

```
>>> [list(x) for x in zip(*l)]
[[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]]
```

Comment: Thank you for the timely response, this works.